# How to communicate mobile (Xamarin) with a desktop Application (.NET)

Tags: xamarin, mobile, xamarin.forms, desktop-application

Is it possible to send some kind of message from mobile app (developed using `Xamarin.forms` with `C#`) to a desktop application (developed using `VB.net` or `C#`)? I would like to send messages from mobile to desktop app. I was thinking on using `Bluetooth` or maybe `WIFI` protocol

Other idea that I was thinkin is making desktop application to use a `rest service`, then also make mobile app to use same `rest server`. In this way It could be possible to create some kind of bridge between these techs.

Do you have any example or any experience on this?

Comment: it is "Client|Server", so tcp/udp, sockets, http(s), etc... all the same whether we are talking local or global network. What data type and content size you are transporting helps make the connection/transport/protocol choices. About the only difference comes in when we start talking local discovery of clients/peers.

Comment: I would like to control buttons or events within a form with Mobile. So I guess Data will only be a sort of variable to select a button

Comment: Try SignalR https://www.asp.net/signalr

Answer (score 1):

You can create a web API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/older-versions/build-restful-apis-with-aspnet-web-api then host it on your desktop/laptop. That would be the channel between your mobile app and your desktop app.